# Android ==> Application development?

Tags: android, device

1. I am an iphone application developer, all iphones have very similar Operating systems, and the size and everything is the same, so I don't need to create applications specific for each iphone.
   But with android there are different phones, different sizes, So How can I possibly know that my app works, and looks fine on all these devices
2. I don't already own an android but I completed my first application using the simulator. Which android phone do u suggest for testing? I am an AT&T user and Iuse an iphone. Can I simply insert my sim-card in the new android to be able to test my app on the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The android virtual device lets you change the virtual hardware to match all of the current shipping phones. There are ways to receive device crash reports from a shipped application to help diagnose force closes or other grievous errors.
2. You need an unlocked phone to use another SIM card. The Nexus One is available unlocked out of the gate, and comes with an AT&T version. The only AT&T (as sold by AT&T) Android phone (Backflip) is stupidly crippled and should be avoided. You can also buy an Android Dev Phone, which is currently "middle of the pack" in terms of hardware. You can also easily find numerous other Android capable handsets - pick depending on your target market. Some phones are now old: for instance, the G1 is on its way out.

Comment: The HTC Aria was just released on AT&T and is a much better option if you are eligible for an upgrade.  If not, I'd go with the Nexus One.

Answer (score 0):

you won't need to worry about different screen size . take a look at  [Supporting Multiple Screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) article . I'm not sure for the late ones because I'm also working with Android Emulator .

Answer (score 0):

1 - Take a look at this [Google IO session](http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/casting-wide-net-android-devices.html) for load of tips on making your app work across devices. It's not that hard at all really

2 - I'd recommend the Nexus One if you need a phone just to develop on. It's representative of what you'll be seeing in devices in the coming years. If you want a current representative phone take a look at the HTC Legend (Mid-end) or the HTC Wildfire (Low-end). There's also the Droid and things like that but you can only get them on Verizon I think. I'm not too knowledgeable about availability in the US, I'm from the UK.